# Getting Invalid hook call Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component with SharePoint Framework Template

Tags: sharepoint-framework, react

I get this

```
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_default.js:26401 [1599066762186][OtherGlobalError.window.onerro] Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

### Steps to reproduce

```
md helloworld-webpart2
cd helloworld-webpart2
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
(select SP Online latest, React)
(modify code like below, add the 1 line of code to add the hook) (helloworld-webpart2\src\webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx)
gulp serve
```

Environment

```
Windows 10
SharePoint Online
Node v10
Chrome v79
VS Code | SPFx v1.10.0
```

Code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './HelloWorld.module.scss';
import { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0); // THIS LINE CAUSES HOOK ISSUE <-----------------
    return (
      <div className={ styles.helloWorld }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I remove that line with the hook, then it works.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message you used in the title to this question says it all:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

What you have there is a *class* component, where you are defining a class that extends another class, and has a `render` function:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
    return (
      // your HTNL
    );
  }
}
```

Whereas, in the React documentation, in the ["Introduction to hooks" page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), it says (emphasis mine):

> *Hooks* are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features **without writing a class**.

Meaning, you have to write a *function* component, which would look a little something like this:

```
  // set up as a function, not a class
  const HelloWorld = props => {

    // your state hook
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)

    return (
        // your HTML
    );
  }

  export default HelloWorld;
```

Now, I'm not quite taking into account how to set that up with Typescript, off the top of my head I think it might be something like:

```
  // set up as a function, not a class
  const HelloWorld = props: IHelloWorldProps => {

    // your state hook
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)

    return (
        // your HTML
    );
  }

  export default HelloWorld;
```

...and there might be more to it than that, again this was just off the top of my head.

But still, the takeaway is: you can use React Hooks inside *function* components, and you cannot use them inside *class* components.